# The pattern is not found by the Dependency Matcher of Spacy

Tags: nlp, spacy

I want to match the pattern like "from xxx to xxx". For example "I want to have a trip from March 4th to 15th.". Here is the parser result.

[image]

The code i have written as follows:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import DependencyMatcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
dependency_matcher = DependencyMatcher(nlp.vocab)

pattern = [
    {
        "RIGHT_ID": "node1",
        "RIGHT_ATTRS": {"LEMMA": "from"}
    },
    {
        "LEFT_ID": "node1",
        "REL_OP": ">",
        "RIGHT_ID": "node2",
        "RIGHT_ATTRS": {"DEP": "pobj"},
    },
    {
        "LEFT_ID": "node1",
        "REL_OP": ">",
        "RIGHT_ID": "node3",
        "RIGHT_ATTRS": {"DEP": 'prep'},
    },
    {
        "LEFT_ID": "node3",
        "REL_OP": ">",
        "RIGHT_ID": "node4",
        "RIGHT_ATTRS": {"DEP": 'pobj'},
    }]
dependency_matcher.add("pattern", [pattern])

text = 'I am looking for a trip from March 4th to 15th.'
doc = nlp(text)
matches = dependency_matcher(doc)
for match_id, token_ids in matches:
    print(nlp.vocab.strings[match_id])
```

but got nothing. I was wondering if i use the text "I want to have a trip from March 4 to 15." the pattern works.

[image]

Do you have some ideas? What is the mistake i made? I am using the model en_core_web_sm with spacy 3.1.0. Thanks!

Comment: Please show your whole code and state what version of spacy you're using (by using the output of `spacy info`, for example).

Comment: I have updated the problem:)

Comment: Are you getting that displaCy output from the web UI, or from your own code? It looks like the web demo output. The web demo is still using spaCy v2, and the dep parse is different with the v3 model. In the v3 model "to"'s head is "trip", not "from".

Comment: Aha, I tried locally！ You are right! Thanks a lot for the tip:)